# Google Polymer: how to properly put divs inside paper-material element?

Tags: html, css, polymer

Here is my code:

```css
.block {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
 }
```

```html
<paper-material elevation="1">
  <p>List of blocks:</p>
  <div class="block">
    <p>Block 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <p>Block 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <p>Block 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <p>Block 4</p>
  </div>
</paper-material>
```

Paper-material element contains only "List of blocks" label, all four divs are outside. How can I fix it so that the divs are inside the paper-material element?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import [iron-flex-layout](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-flex-layout) and add `@apply --layout-horiztonal;` to your CSS, which currently amounts to

```
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
-ms-flex-direction: row;
-webkit-flex-direction: row;
flex-direction: row;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Hovewer, when I use inline-block property, the last block moves below as if it does not have enough space.

Comment: I changed it to ensure single line.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add div at the end of all `.block` divs and set style `clear: both`

inside style:

```
.block {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
 }

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

and paper-material:

```
<paper-material elevation="1">
  <p>List of blocks:</p>
  <div class="block">
    <p>Block 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <p>Block 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <p>Block 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
    <p>Block 4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</paper-material>
```

but this is still not the best solution. Since your paper-material should have fixed width. At this moment it is better to use [display: flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) . Be aware that older IE doesn't support flex. So if you really want to support that 1% of people then you can continue using `float:left`.. but i still think using `display: inline-block` would be much more better.